# How to fetch a list of all svg files from an angular application directory?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to fetch a list of all `.svg` files inside a specific folder of my Angular 4 application. Therefore I am already declaring the folder in my `angular-cli.json` file via

```
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "favicon.ico",
        "assets",
        {
          "glob": "**/*.svg",
          "input": "../node_modules/..../assets/images",
          "output": "./assets/images"
        }
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "ma...
```

**How am I able now to read a list of all `.png` files inside my `./assets/images` directory?**
The list should be loaded inside a standard angular component. Afterwards I want iterate over the list using a simple for loop. I can do the last part by my own if some of you can tell me how to get the list.

---

**EDIT**

The content of the directory looks something like this

```
images
|--file_1.svg
|--file_2.svg
|--file_3.svg
└--file_4.svg
```

If I try to acces the url [HOST:PORT/assets/images/file_1.svg](http://aa) the image is displayed correct, but if I try to list all files of the directory using [HOST:PORT/assets/images](http://aa) an `HTTP 404` occurs.

Here is the constructor of my component:

```
constructor(private http: Http) {
   this.http.get('./assets/images').subscribe(res => console.log(res));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried my best to find a solution for this but it appears impossible as Javascript does not have access to the file structure. The best solution I can find is to create a list of icons in a json, request the file and then store the contents for later user.

[I have found this example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54420869/1457219)

As accessing file from `assets` folder is easy, so we can exploit it
 and we can store an array of icon file names in the file say, `icons.json`.

**1.** Create `icons.json` as following in the `assets` folder-

```
{  // ---------- icons.json---------
  "icons-array" : ["icon-name1", "icon-name2", "icon-name3"]
}
```

**2.** Keep `icon-name1.svg`, `icon-name2.svg`, `icon-name3.svg` file in the `assets/icons` folder.

**3.** Read `icons-json` file at start-up of the angular application. 
      **[How to read file at Angular Application Start-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54176684/how-to-change-urls-automatically-in-services-after-changing-url-it-should-affec/54178616#54178616)**
**4.**   After reading `icons.json` content, store value of `icons-array` property into a global accessible array, say     `globalAccessibleIconsArray`.

 **5.**  And use the array as-

```
for (const icon of globalAccessibleIconsArray) {
      this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIconInNamespace(
        'my-namespace',
        icon,
        domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(`./assets/icons/${icon}.svg`)
      );
    }
```

So, for Adding a new icon

- you have to put the new icon file in the `assets/icon` folder, and
- add the new file name in the `icons.json` file present in the `assets` folder.